# Trigger to insert on referenced table on fk failure?

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-keys

Is it possible to create a trigger to insert a record into a referenced table on a foreign key constraint in MySQL?

Let's say I have a table `services` with `services.service_id` and a table `service_log` with `service_log.service_id` referencing `services.service_id` and another field called `service_log.log_id`.

Upon failure of an insert into `service_log` because of an invalid `service_id`, is it possible to then create a trigger that would insert into `services` with a new `service_id` such that the original insert could be made afterwords (preferably in one step automatically)?

Comment: You could have a BEFORE INSERT trigger check the referenced table and perform the insert if needed.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean the before insert would have to check every insert? Wouldn't that double the query time?

Comment: Potentially, that is why you shouldn't be inserting values not already in the referenced table; ideally, you should generally not be referencing "real" data that a user would be inputting anyway (it should be referencing a surrogate key such as an auto-increment field or a predetermined set of values such as you would find in a client-side enum). If you want to let users create their own "service ids" the code should insert those and retrieve the database's id created for the service.

Comment: You can also define an error handler in an after insert trigger. But i can't tell you if that would be any faster or slower. But i agree with @Uueerdo that your idea is not the best one.